# Lavaplayer "dependency not found"

Tags: java, maven, lavaplayer

I am trying to import lavaplayer in my Maven pom.xml file. The issue is that there seems to be an error with importing it.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>dv8tion</id>
        <name>m2-dv8tion</name>
        <url>https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-alpha.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sedmelluq</groupId>
        <artifactId>lavaplayer</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The second import in dependencies is red, the error being that the library is not found. What could I bed doing wrong?

Comment: The version is 1.3.77 or 1.3.78, not 1.3.7

Comment: The given repository `https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases` seemed to only accessible via credentials... do you have them?

Comment: changing  to 1.3.77 sadly still has the same issue, but thank you for the suggestion. I was confused as to why that link showed a "NoSuchKey" code. I will try and workout how to get credentials for it. Thanks!